# CSS relative size columns unequal width problem

Tags: css, grid, width, gutter

I'm trying to implement relative width columns based on the oocss framework. In order to add a gutter in between the columns I added an inner div in between the columns and their content.

The problem is that I end up with columns of unequal width...

I could avoid this by having the same padding for the first and last columns but since I want to nest columns it would create a shift on the right and the left...

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WxPSm/2/

Any idea welcomed!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.unit > .content:first-child {
padding: 0 2em;
```

}

The problem is with your inner .content divs.  The middle column has padding being applied on both sides where as the left column only has padding on the right and the right column has only padding on the left.

The outer unit divs are all the same size.  Using firebug to inspect the elements highlights the padding very well if you need a visual.